# Singleton class and correct way to access it in C++

Tags: c++, c++11, singleton

I'm currently trying to implement the singleton pattern in C++. After reading about it for a while now, it seems like there are a really large amount of different ways to do this.

Is the way I ended up doing it correct or did I miss out on something important here? Is this implementation thread safe in modern C++ (I read there were some changes to that in particular with C++11)? In addition I am not sure at all about the way I am accessing the class within `MyFunction()`.

Is it really necessary to use a raw pointer there? Does this code contain any memory leaks?

```
#include <iostream>

class Singleton
{
private:

    Singleton();
    ~Singleton();  

public:

    static Singleton& instance()
    {
        static Singleton INSTANCE;
        return INSTANCE;
    }

    void Test();
};

void Singleton::Test()
{
    std::cout << "Test() called" << std::endl;
}

Singleton::Singleton()
{
    std::cout << "CONSTRUCTOR CALLED" << std::endl;
}

Singleton::~Singleton()
{
    std::cout << "DESTRUCTOR CALLED" << std::endl;
}

void MyFunction()
{
    // use the singleton class
    Singleton * MySingleton = &Singleton::instance();   
    MySingleton->Test();    
}


int main()
{
    MyFunction();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I'd disable copyctor and `=` so that you won't accidentally copy the object.

Comment: BTW, it is perfectly thread-safe, because static variable initialization is thread-safe

Answer (score 8):

## Thread safety

Accessing the singleton is thread-safe. The change in C++11 has forced compilers to implement the construction of local `static` variables (like `INSTANCE`) in a thread-safe manner.

Note, however, that this doesn't make `Singleton` thread-safe under all circumstances: If multiple threads are calling `Singleton::Test`, I wouldn't be surprised to see some garbled output, as access to `std::cout` isn't synchronized.

## Correctness

The current implementation violates the rule of 5: It has a custom destructor, but no custom copy and move constructors and assignment operators. And, to prevent making a copy of the singleton instance (or moving from it!), these 4 special functions should be deleted, like so:

```
public:
    Singleton(const Singleton&) = delete;
    Singleton(Singleton&&) = delete;
    Singleton& operator=(const Singleton&) = delete;
    Singleton& operator=(Singleton&&) = delete;
```

Note the `public` specifier, this ensures that these deletions are visible everywhere needed.

## Access

While taking a pointer from the reference returned by `Singleton::instance()` is a valid use, it seems unnecessary in `MyFunction` as the pointer isn't required. Why not simply capture by a reference, like so:

```
auto& MySingleton = Singleton::instance();
MySingleton.Test();
```

Or if only one call is done:

```
Singleton::instance().Test();
```

Comment: Note, too, that many consider Singletons to be an anti-pattern and prefer using different approaches if feasible.

Comment: Kevlin Henney likes to note that it is ironic that programs never have exactly one singleton.  They either have none or a bunch.  I agree it is a mistake to start with “I need a singleton”.  Rather, what is it that you really want to accomplish?  That will help guide which form of (possibly singleton-like) behavior you want to implement.

Comment: Why the move constractor and move assignment should be deleted? Isn't it safe to move a singleton object?

Comment: @hsalimi the idea behind a Singleton is that there can only ever be one instance. Moving a Singleton instance means creating a new one. Assigning to a Singleton instance means that there is more than one instance in existence. Both operations violate the Singleton idea (plus you might get additional headaches if `Singleton::instance()` got moved from).

Comment: @hoffmale I do not agree that moving a singleton object means creting a new one. IMHO, moving means just passing the internals of the singleton object to a new object or pointer.

Comment: @hsalimi Moving an object means either creating an new one (via move constructor) or assigning to an existing one (via move assignment). Both cases mean that there are (or at least will be) multiple instances of the Singleton class. But the idea of a Singleton is that there will only ever be at most one instance. Thus, being able to move from a Singleton is undesirable.

Comment: @hoffmale mmmm ... not convinced yet. It is true that in move constructor, an object is created, but the other one will not exist anymore. So, it means that if you move a singleton object, either through move constructor or move assignement, the object will remain singleton as well.

Comment: @hsalimi: As said, the idea behind a singleton is that there will only ever be one instance (and that one always at the same location). That means being able to assign to an instance is undesirable, as just having another instance should be impossible. Similar reasoning for move constructor: You shouldn't be able to create a second instance in another location. Remember: Move constructing a new object doesn't destroy the old one. `MyType a; MyType b{std::move(a)};` Now `a` still exists, although in an empty state. The constructor should be deleted so this cannot happen.

Comment: Yeah, you are right, esp. in this scenario: If the original object that is created inside getInstance() is moved, it will be empty. The next time, this empty object will be returened to a new client asking for an instance, and it is not good anymore..

Answer (score 1):

You have created the classic Singleton pattern for C++.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/1008289/14065

This is great as a learning exercise. But in real life you can't use the Singleton like that because it tightly couples the objects to the things that use it. For instance testing your code now becomes exceeedingly difficult.

To use a s Singleton well (so it is not considered an anti pattern) you also need to combine the Singletons with another builder pattern (most will work but factory is easiest).
https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/40374/12917

You may have a default version of a Singleton that is run in production. But you should be able to configure the system so that at runtime the Singleton that is built at run-time is dependent on situation (so for testing you always insatiate an appropriate test Singleton).

## Code Review:

#### Copying

You should prevent copying/moving of the object. If you allow copying it is no longer a Singleton, if you allow moving then it is it valid? Disable the copy/move constructors and assignment operators.

#### Usage

```
    // No reason to use a pointer.
    Singleton * MySingleton = &Singleton::instance();

    // When you have a pointer there is no ownership semantics
    // associated. So it is easy to make a mistake and accidentally
    // call delete on the pointer.


    // It returns a reference, so capture a reference
    Singleton&  MySingleton = Singleton::instance(); 

    // Here ownership semantics are clear.
    // You don't own the object (you simply have a reference to it).
    // It is your responsibility to make sure the object has not been
    // destroyed since you retrieved the reference.

    // Thus usually easier to use a Singleton as soon as you get it.
    Singleton::instance().Test();   // Don't need to keep a ref.
```

Answer (score 0):

The way you have it will initialize the instance the first time it is used, if ever.  That is handy for a component that may or may not be needed, and as an attempt to get dependencies between such systems automatically correct.

It will be destroyed during program shut down, after `main` returns (so, no memory leak), in the reverse order that such scoped static variables were created.  If it gets used *after* that, you will have problems.  Some singletons such as a logger may very well get used that way.  You have no way to trap such bad uses, which is the downside of letting the compiler handle the details of creation and destruction.

---

[⧺Enum.5](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#enum5-dont-use-all_caps-for-enumerators) *Don't use `ALL_CAPS` for enumerators* and [⧺ES.9](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#es9-avoid-all_caps-names) *Avoid `ALL_CAPS` names*.

Comment: It is easy to solve the order of shut down issue. So that your Singleton is never used illegally. https://stackoverflow.com/a/335746/14065

Comment: Some arbitrary utility function logs something (a problem, or just chatter inserted while trying to find a bug) and it is called from here and there and anywhere, unrelated to the business-level objects at the top of the app.  So how does controlling the order of creation and destruction of the systems help you?  If *anything* runs after log has been destroyed, it *might* log something and Boom.

Comment: By controlling the order of destruction of the log (so that it is the last thing to be destroyed). You have solved the problem. If the log is the last thing to go nothing can use it after it has been destroyed.

Comment: You can't control the total global order.  The method linked will make it last among those wrapped local static variables that follow the protocol, but global scope variables will be destroyed after those.  Note that "global ctor and dtor" is specifically a place where we want to log problems, since errors there just prevent loading or give mysterious crash on shutdown.

Comment: As I said it is easy to solve the problem. If you want to force logging to be destroyed after your component has logged follow the protocol. Then the log object will be destroyed after yours. You can't prevent errors but this problem is a solved problem.